# Error when attempting to debug an app on iPhone which was previously working

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I had been debugging my iOS application successfully for some time before I put the development on the back burner for a while (about 4 months).  Apparently in that time something has changed because now I get the error:

`Failed to codesign 'bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone8.2-15.2/OML_iOS.app': Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: Prescott Chartier (CGGJVT9YJC)"`

I have been unable to find any information on this error.  I'm using Visual Studio 2022 paired with a MAC.  Both machines have been updated with the most recent versions of Visual Studio and XCode.  I think my issue may be related the the following link:

https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration

But I cannot be sure and Apple requires that you pay for any support or explanation of their information, I'm too poor for that.  Lol  If anyone can assist me with this issue, I would appreciate it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I has suspected, the issue was related to the information at the link I had provided.  I downloaded and installed the `Worldwide Developer Relations - G3 (Expiring 02/20/2030 00:00:00 UTC)` from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ to my Macbook and the issue went away.  The cert that was installed indicated that it was still valid but apparently not, perhaps it was revoked by Apple I really don't know.